# Is it possible to generate a hidden file that will force window's folder view settings for a given folder?

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

Thanks in advance for any of your comments / suggestions

My research tells me that windows 10 folder view options are stored in the registry's bagMRU tree, and that each folder i manually change is stored in an entry there.

my question, is it possible to have a file that resides in the folder that will override or provide a default view for the folder upon navigation?

I'm imagining a .htaccess style file that windows will pick up

here's the rationale;

I generate a lot of folders for image sorting as part of my job at work, and have these default folders created as a template that i simply copy into the project directory and populate with images

it would be nice if i could include a hidden file that windows would read and have it force the view mode to "large icons".

Every time i make a new folder set, this setting would be provided every time and eliminate the need to click view > large icons for each and every folder....
I make a lot of these folders so i spend a lot of time clicking view settings

As these are all stored on network drives, my settings are lost quite often when the connection is reset, and my manual view changes are only applied to me, not the rest of our organization's users...

If its not possible, then i will accept it and move on and thanks for your consideration - if it IS possible, please let me know your approaches!

Thanks very much

Lukesaber

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: No, without any external software and even that would be trivial. In macOS you could manipulate .DS_Store by some chance but Windows only stores thumbnail database in Thumbs.db, not the folder settings.

If you like to have the default view for all folders, open explorer window and go to the folder of images. Right-click, View, select "Large icons". From the view drop down menu at the top left select "Options". Go to "View" -tab and select "Apply to folders". Now large icons will be default for all folders.